Why do we use elliptic curves instead of just the discrete logarithm problem?
We have a cyclic field Fp where p is a prime number, a generator g, and an order n. A generator is an element such that $g^n=1$. A random number x has been chosen as the private key, selected from the interval from 1 to n−1. Then the public key will be $y=g^x$. The discrete logarithm problem is to determine x given y and g. This problem is hard (or hard only on elliptic curves?). Why do we need elliptic curves instead of just using a cyclic field and a generator?

I suppose you meant "cyclic group". In short, (most) Elliptic curves used in crypto are also cyclic group. Their advantage is great efficiency, minimal size and a good record of resisting attempts to solve dlog efficiently(some curves are better than others). Finite field dlog can be attacked by specialised attacks.

What is so special about elliptic curves?

Discrete Logarithm: What does it mean to find the discrete logarithm of
to base
modulo
?

Is is correct below? : in elliptic curve problem discrete logarithm is replaced by problem of division.We have cyclic subgroup of point P: {O,P,2P,3P...(n-1)P}, private key d is chosen from [1..n-1] and public key is Q = dP

What you write is essentially correct but it's still called discrete log in the Elliptic Curve group, not division

My impression is dated (by twenty years or so), but I think that it is still all about the DLP being more difficult on an elliptic curve in comparison to a finite field (where we have index calculus and all that jazz). In other words, you get a more secure system for the same (or similar) key size.
